# If I heat a solution to bring a solute in solution, will it precipitate when it goes back to room temperature?

Tags: solubility, temperature

Suppose I'd like to bring a solute into solution at a concentration above its solubility at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$, so I heat the solution and achieve a concentration above the $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$ solubility. Once the solution is back to room temperature, will the solute precipitate?

Comment: Mostly likely it will. This is called recrystallisation and is often used to purify a crystallisable material

Comment: Or it won't. This is called a supersaturated solution (honey often is supersaturated).

Comment: and can a supersaturated solution stay so for a very long time, or will it eventually precipitate? I'm interested specifically in amino acids like adenine hemisulfate that seem to have low solubility in water, but many protocols suggest preparing stock solutions with concentrations above the room temperature solubility by warming the solution, and I'm worried that they may slowly precipitate with time

Comment: Another good example is glycerol, which melts at $17.9°$C. But it can be kept liquid for years at much lower temperatures, due to its high viscosity. During my chemistry studies, I remember the professor told us once that the first crystals had been obtained in a flask of glycerin that was nearly forgotten in winter in a truck in a railway station in northern Sweden. Apparently these unique crystals have been used later on for starting the crystallization of all the glycerin crystals in the world.

Comment: The you should add this detail to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, your conclusion is correct However:

- As mentioned in comments, supersaturated solutions can endure for a *long* time: consider the $\ce{NaCH3COO.3H2O}$ [heating pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_acetate#Heating_pad), which dissolves in its own water of crystallization at 58°C, and doesn't crystalize, even when greatly cooled, until disturbed (e.g., by a "clicker"). Similarly, starting crystallization can be difficult, requiring [additional chemicals and seed crystals](https://journals.iucr.org/d/issues/2010/08/00/bw5361/), or [ultrasound](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343843174_Ultrasonic_protein_crystallization_Promoting_nucleation_in_microdroplets_through_pulsed_sonication), or just [scratching a glass vessel](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_Lab_Techniques_(Nichols)/03:_Crystallization/3.05:_Procedural_Generalities/3.5E:_Initiating_Crystallization).
- Another possibility is a [retrograde temperature solubility curve](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mystery-solubility-retrograde-temperature-inverse-why-mukherjee). Common calcium sulfate,[$\ce{CaSO4}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_sulfate#Retrograde_solubility) and [lead halide perovskites](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/cc/c5cc06916e) are far *less* soluble in hot solutions. In that case, one would *chill* the solution to completely dissolve the solute, and slowly *heat* it to promote precipitation and crystallization! BTW, that's why precipitates from heating water cause boilers (and percolators) to need occasional "descaling".

Comment: A nice answer, but it talks rather about exceptions than rules. Generally, it will crystallize, the time would differ. //Scale deposition is mostly due Ca/Mg carbonates.  Solubility of CaSO4.2H2O is 2.55/2.05 g/L at 20/100 °C, so unless it is very mineralised mineral water, it would stay dissolved.